Cannot use llm_chat_callback on an instance without a callback_manager attribute
model_key = {"OpenAI": ["gpt-3.5-turbo","gpt-4"]}

def get_embeddingmodel(self, model_name,api_key):
    if model_name in model_key["OpenAI"]:
     return OpenAIEmbedding(api_key=api_key)

This is my method to return the Embeddings Model based on the modelname and its APi key, and below is the code snippet where it uses the returned embedding model for indexing:
    service_context=ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm=self.model,embed_model=self.embeding_model,callback_manager=callback_manager)
index = VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(doc,llm=self.model,service_context=service_context)

But I am getting this error while running:ValueError:
Cannot use llm_chat_callback on an instance without a callback_manager attribute.

This is for an llm chatbot, thus the expected results, is if we ask a question from a context it should answer.

how are you creating the callback_manager?

callback_manager = CallbackManager([llama_debug])
service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(
llm=self.model,embed_model=self.embeding_model,callback_manager=callback_manager
)
index=VectorStoreIndex.from_documents(doc,llm=self.model,service_context=service_context)
